# Oculus rift DK2 setup

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, oculus-rift

Ok, so I've purchased the Oculus rift DK2 and whenever I want to use it I have to use it in extended mode and use the direct to rift apps, this means I don't always get to play everything. When the Oculus Rift DK2 is plugged into my desktop via HDMI it acts as a second monitor and I can adjust it settings that way. When I play my games with the rift I am unable to view the game on my monitor and on my rift due to the fact that it is in extended mode and sometimes my mouse goes out of the range in the extended mode. I would like to duplicate the displays, however the Oculus rift when used is on one side, so I have to set it as extended and then hit portrait so the rotation looks normal. Is there a way to have the rift duplicate what is seen on my main monitor and for it to be rotated without the main display being rotated. I have an AMD card, so if it involves the catalyst I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the new 0.5.0.1 runtime is much better for direct mode. I'd start with upgrading to that version, making sure you have the latest firmware and then testing the Tuscany demo in direct mode.